# TextField MUI not detecting change in value when "ctrl + a" && "backspace/delete" clicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

here's a link to the problem :

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hooks-ddce6c?file=/src/App.js

when i hit backspace erasing each character the textfield detects the change in value, but when i select all with ctrl + a and hit backspace or delete it doesn't detect the change in value.

PS: the value in the

tag changes and that can seem misleading, please check the console log value it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

```
const onChangeForm = (keyName, keyValue) => {
    let temp_value = keyValue;
    if (keyName === "domainName" && temp_value) {
      temp_value = temp_value.trim();
      console.log(temp_value);
    }
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      ...{ [keyName]: temp_value }
    });
  };
```

instead of if(keyName === "domainName" && temp_value) use if(keyName === "domainName")
that check neglects empty values.